# Add ssh key to Xcode bot (into _xcsbuildd user)

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I have Xcode build server with some bots. I need to execute a pre-integration script. This script should execute next command:

```
git lfs pull
```

Unfortunately in pre-integration script phase, this script doesn't see ssh keys, that the bot uses to make pull from git, therefore that command returns a error. 
I know that pre-integration script executes via _xcsbuildd user.
How I can add ssh key, to _xcsbuildd user or, get his key?